# convert a Julian date to gregorian date in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to convert a integer column with  Julian date values to gregorian date in netezza sql. The source  column has values like '41606', '100702', please help

Comment: Does this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35223624/1832954 ?

Comment: @Izanagi  Most certainly not, because the question you refer to talks about dates encoded in  a `C-YY-DDD` format (ie century, year within century, day within year). But the above numbers seem to be something different. Or what would the 606th day of year 41 be?

Comment: But It also doesn't seem to be a julian day number (ie number of days since January 1, 4713 BC. Because for that, current dates should be around 2 500 000 ... So without knowing what these values acutally are, it's quite impossible to help

Comment: Please provide example input AND output values. Nobody here knows for sure what ‘100702’ means, but if it literally IS a Julian date it’s thousands of years into the future (today it’s the 28th march 2024 and it’s Julian 24088) https://www.longpelaexpertise.com.au/toolsJulian.php

Comment: @LarsGOlsen  With the converter you linked, both values given above are not "thousands of years into the future", but just invalid  because a year only has 365 (or 366) days and thus `...702`  or `...606` makes no sense in this system, where the last three digits denote the day of the year .... Ie using that system `100702` would be tze 702th day of the year 2000

Comment: I get it - and stand corrected… would still like to see expected output together with input…. Makes it easier to help